# elementary OS Calendar syncs oneway only with Google Calendar

Tags: release-odin, calendar

My elementary OS calendar syncs oneway with my Google calendar. Let me explain:

If I add an event in the elementary OS calendar it appears in my Google calendar.
If I add an event in my Gogle calendar nothing appears in my elementary OS calendar.

Does anyone else get this?

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the calendar is not setup for real time syncing. Have you tried rebooting and then re-checking the calendar to see if it shows up?

Comment: I was about to edit my question, that a reboot actually fixed the issue! Thanks Matt!

Answer (score 0):

I have two parallel accounts with another email provider. One account syncs both ways flawlessly. The other account only syncs one way (from calendar app to server), but does not download existing events.
Rebooting does not work.
The URL I used is the direct link to the calendar.

Every time I uncheck/check the calendar in the settings, I get an error message with the following content:

*Connection to ... failed. Backend for source..... and plugin "calendar" cannot be found.*

Do you have any ideas?
TIA

Comment: What is the provider? That is kind of a crucial info to include.